# Cómo aumentar la memoria IDE Android Studio?

Tags: android-studio

Últimamente he desarrollado para Android, y he notado que el IDE Android Studio toma demasiado tiempo para cargar y comenzar.

Entonces me pregunto: ¿cómo aumentar la memoria IDE Android Studio?

Para iniciar el IDE más rápido y por lo tanto el desarrollo más rápido.

Comment: Yo aumento la velocidad de Instant Run en Android Studio 2.1 con org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx2048m mirate https://medium.com/google-developers/faster-android-studio-builds-with-dex-in-process-5988ed8aa37e#.oqwiii748

Comment: tambien podrias usar tu smartphone android como emulador para que tu computadora no se lagee.
Saludos

Answer (score 5):

### Configuración de la memoria adecuada para Android Studio IDE

La respuesta la encontré en un [artículo](http://imasters.com.br/mobile/android/ambiente-de-desenvolvimento-android-lento-demorado-chato-aqui-nao), y tomó como base de mi respuesta y decidí compartir aquí en SOes.

Android de estudio, de forma predeterminada (por defecto), viene configurado con poca memoria, por lo que es tan lento para empezar, carga, desarrollar y desplegar.

El secreto aquí es utilizar un PC con al menos 4 GB de RAM y poner al menos 2 GB para Android Studio.

¿Como hacer?

En la carpeta de instalación tiene una carpeta llamada bin (por ejemplo, `C:\Archivos de programa\Android\Android Studio\bin`) y, dentro de ella, hay 2 archivos: `studio.exe.vmoptions` y `studio64.exe.vmoptions`. Si utiliza PC de 32 bits, cambie los `studio.exe.vmoptions`. Si utiliza 64 bits, cambiar a la otra. configurar correctamente xmx, XMS, PermSize, cachesize y otra interna.

### ** Advertencia Importante **

> Antes de editar los archivos `studio.exe.vmoptions` y
>   `studio64.exe.vmoptions`, saben que son los archivos protegidos,
>   entonces, no es suficiente para editar y guardar, se le dará error,
>   Android estudio no permite editar y guardar el archivo directamente en
>   la papelera, a continuación, la carpeta, que va a hacer es hacer clic
>   en el botón derecho sobre el archivo, seleccione abrir con el Bloc de
>   notas, editar el archivo y el tiempo de guardar, se guarda el archivo
>   de modo -> Nombre: `estudio.exe.vmoptions`, Tipo: `Todos los archivos (*)` y guárdelo en su `escritorio(desktop)` y después de haber guardado, que es
>   donde se copia el nuevo archivo que aparece en su pantalla y pegar en
>   la carpeta bin y reemplazar el archivo anterior, que el procedimiento
>   habitual - donde las ventanas le pedirán que `desea sobrescribir el archivo antiguo con lo nuevo` y hace clic en `Sí, me desea reemplazar el archivo antiguo con lo nuevo` y ahora todo está bien, que haya
>   actualizado el reemplazo para el archivo!

Vea el archivo `studio.exe.vmoptions` a continuación, probablemente debería estar con valores muy bajos, como este:

```
#
# *DO NOT* modify this file directly. If there is a value that you would like to override,
# please add it to your user specific configuration file.
#
# See http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/configuration
#
-server
-Xms256m
-Xmx750m
-XX:MaxPermSize=350m
-XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=240m
-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC
-XX:SoftRefLRUPolicyMSPerMB=50
-da
-Djna.nosys=true
-Djna.boot.library.path=

-Djna.debug_load=true
-Djna.debug_load.jna=true
-Dsun.io.useCanonCaches=false
-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true
-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError
-Didea.paths.selector=AndroidStudio2.1
-Didea.platform.prefix=AndroidStudio
```

Modificar el siguiente pasaje:

```
-Xms256m
-Xmx2048m
-XX:MaxPermSize=512m
-XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=512m
-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC
-XX:SoftRefLRUPolicyMSPerMB=150
```

Una vez que haya modificado el fragmento anterior, guarde el archivo en el escritorio(desktop), de esta manera:

- Nombre: `studio.exe.vmoptions`
- Tipo: `Todos los archivos (*)`

Una vez que haya guardado, que es donde se copia el nuevo archivo que aparece en su pantalla y pegar en la carpeta bin y sustituye a la anterior por el archivo.

Vea el archivo `studio64.exe.vmoptions` a continuación, probablemente debería estar con valores muy bajos, como este:

```
#
# *DO NOT* modify this file directly. If there is a value that you would like to override,
# please add it to your user specific configuration file.
#
# See http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/configuration
#
-Xms256m
-Xmx1280m
-XX:MaxPermSize=350m
-XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=240m
-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC
-XX:SoftRefLRUPolicyMSPerMB=50
-da
-Djna.nosys=true
-Djna.boot.library.path=

-Djna.debug_load=true
-Djna.debug_load.jna=true
-Dsun.io.useCanonCaches=false
-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true
-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError
-Didea.paths.selector=AndroidStudio2.1
-Didea.platform.prefix=AndroidStudio
```

Modificar el siguiente pasaje:

```
 -Xms256m
 -Xmx2048m
 -XX:MaxPermSize=512m
 -XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=512m
 -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC
 -XX:SoftRefLRUPolicyMSPerMB=150
```

Una vez que haya modificado el fragmento anterior, guarde el archivo en el escritorio(desktop), de esta manera:

- Nombre: `studio64.exe.vmoptions`
- Tipo: `Todos los archivos (*)`

Una vez que haya guardado, que es donde se copia el nuevo archivo que aparece en su pantalla y pegar en la carpeta bin y sustituye a la anterior por el archivo.

---

He ayudado ahora actualizar los archivos e iniciar el IDE Android de estudio, y se verá que Android está empezando Estudio mucho más rápido!

Comment: Mi Android Studio si funcionaba ahora al cambiar eso me puso este problema
Failed to create JVM:error code -6.
JVM Path: C:\Program Files\Android Studio\jre\jre
If you already have a 64-bit JDK installed, define a JAVA_HOME variable in
Computer> System Properties> System Settings> Environment Variables.

Answer (score 0):

Yo tambien tenía el mismo problema, mi Android Studio iba lentisimo, tardaba mucho en hacer cualquier cosa...

Despues de investigar mucho me encontré esto en SO:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30817871/android-studio-is-slow-how-to-speed-up

La respuesta de Werner Schäffer dice lo siguiente:

> He detectado otra razón - Thumbs.db, que afecta muchisimo a la performance:
>       Ve a File > Settings > Editor > File Types y en el campo Ignore files and folders añade lo siguiente: Thumbs.db;

A mi despues de hacer esto no he vuelto a tener problemas, todo va como un tiro.